# How to reduce subquery execution time...?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want per day sales item count so for that one i already created query but it takes to much around 55.585s and query is

Query :

```
SELECT
td.db_date,
(
  select count(*) from order as order where DATE(order.created_on) = td.db_date
)as day_contribute
FROM time_dimension as td
```

So can any one please let me know how may i optimized this query and reduce execution time.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your query to join like:

```
SELECT
td.db_date, count(order.id) as day_contribute
FROM time_dimension as td
LEFT JOIN order ON DATE(order.created_on) = td.db_date
GROUP BY td.db_date;
```

I do not know your primary id key for table order - so used just "order.id". Replace it with your.

Also it is very important - test if you have index on td.db_date field.

And one more important thing - better to avoid using DATE(order.created_on). Because it is mean that DATE() method will be called each time when DB will compare dates. If it is possible - convert order.created_on to same format as td.db_date. Or join by other fields. That will add speed too.

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir Gilevich : it really help me to reduce query exection time but still it tacke around 28.457s so if you any trick then please let know

Comment: @L.V.Patadiya to tell something more I need to know more :) Can you provide here structure of your tables "td" and "order" to understand better what can be improved here?

Comment: td table has only one filed which is date another table is order where there are so many field are there..

Comment: @L.V.Patadiya I'm asking about schema - to understand - do you have index for "order.created_on" and "td.db_date" fields or no? If no - add it then. Request will looks like: `ALTER TABLE td ADD INDEX (db_date);` and same for order table: `ALTER TABLE order ADD INDEX (created_on);`

Comment: And you already tried with "LEFT JOIN order ON order.created_on = td.db_date" instead "LEFT JOIN order ON DATE(order.created_on) = td.db_date", right?

Comment: What do you meant by it takes time? Btw. If you need speed with this request - you can cache results. So only first request will take more time. I want to tell - you can try not only improving request - you can try change things around to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

First you should make sure you have index on `created_on` column in `order` table.

However if you have many records in `time_dimension` and many records in `order` table it might be hard to optimize the query, because for each record from `time_dimension` you need to search in `order` table.

You can also change `count(*)` into `count(order_id)` (assuming primary key in `order` table is `order_id`) or add extra column with date only in `order` table (`created_on_date` with date only and index on this column) so your query could look like this:

```
SELECT
td.db_date,
(
  select count(order_id) from order where order.created_on_date = td.db_date
)as day_contribute
FROM time_dimension as td
```

However it's possible the execution time might be too high if you have many records in both tables, so it might be necessary to create one extra table where you hold number of orders for each day and update it in cron or when adding/updating/deleting records in `order` table